# How to show UI from Notification

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to make a simple musicPlayer that works on Android device.To make Background-play come true, I'm using Service class.

What I want to do is below:
1.User launches app and taps start button
2.Music starts and Notification that notes the Music is playing appears
3.User taps home button and the app's UI disappears
4.Music doesn't stop
5.User tap Notification
6.UI appears with disabled start button and enabled stop button ← I'm in trouble

With My Code, UI appears. But it is not the UI which user made to disappear. How do I describe...It is new-ed UI. 
So when user taps stop button,of course music doesn't stop. The Service is different one.
I want music to stop.
Is there any way to show the first created UI? the original UI?
If there's no way to show first created UI,how can I reach to first running service?

Thank you for browsing.

My Activity

```
    package com.websarva.wings.android.servicesample;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
    
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.content.ServiceConnection;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServiceConnection {
    
        public static final String LOG_TAG = "ServiceSample:";
    
        private Intent _intent;
        public static final String INTENT_ACTION = "intentAction";
    
        private ServiceConnection _connection = new ServiceConnection(){
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
    
            }
        };
    
        public void onPlayButtonClick(View view){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                    "#onPlayButtonClick -_intentHash - " + _intent.hashCode()
                            + "-_connectionHash" + _connection.hashCode());
    
            bindService(_intent, _connection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(_intent);
    
            Button btPlay = findViewById(R.id.btPlay);
            btPlay.setEnabled(false);
            Button btStop = findViewById(R.id.btStop);
            btStop.setEnabled(true);
        }
    
        public void onStopButtonClick(View view){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                    "#onStopButtonClick -_intentHash - " + _intent.hashCode()
                            + "-_connectionHash" + _connection.hashCode());
            unbindService(_connection);
            stopService(_intent);
            Button btStop = findViewById(R.id.btStop);
            btStop.setEnabled(false);
            Button btPlay = findViewById(R.id.btPlay);
            btPlay.setEnabled(true);
        }
    
        private BroadcastReceiver _MessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Button btStop = findViewById(R.id.btStop);
                btStop.setEnabled(false);
                Button btPlay = findViewById(R.id.btPlay);
                btPlay.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(_MessageReceiver,new IntentFilter(INTENT_ACTION));
            _intent = getIntent();
            boolean isAlreadyPlaying = _intent.getBooleanExtra(SoundManageService.EXTRA_KEY_ISPLAYING,false);
            if(isAlreadyPlaying){
                Button btPlay = findViewById(R.id.btPlay);
                btPlay.setEnabled(false);
                Button btStop = findViewById(R.id.btStop);
                btStop.setEnabled(true);
            }
            _intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SoundManageService.class);
            bindService(_intent, _connection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(_MessageReceiver);
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

My Service

```
    package com.websarva.wings.android.servicesample;
    
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
    import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleService;
    import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    
    public class SoundManageService extends LifecycleService{
    
        public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "soundmanagerservice_notification_channel";
        public static final int FINISH_NOTIFICATION_ID = 2;
        public static final int START_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        public static final String EXTRA_KEY_ISPLAYING = "isPlaying";
    
        MediaPlayer _player;
    
        public SoundManageService() {
        }
    
        private class PlayerPreparedListener implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{
    
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SoundManageService.this,CHANNEL_ID);
                builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
                builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.msg_notification_title_start));
                builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.msg_notification_text_start));
                Intent intent = new Intent(SoundManageService.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_ISPLAYING,mp.isPlaying());
                PendingIntent stopServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        SoundManageService.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                builder.setContentIntent(stopServiceIntent);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                startForeground(START_NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
            }
        }
    
        private class PlayerCompletionListener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
    
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopSelf();
                sendMessage();
            }
        }
    
        private void sendMessage() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.INTENT_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(){
            super.onCreate();
            _player = new MediaPlayer();
            String channelName = getString(R.string.notification_channnel_name);
            int notificationImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,channelName,notificationImportance);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    
            @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
                super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
                String mediaUriStr ="android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.testmusic;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(mediaUriStr);
                _player = new MediaPlayer();
                try{
                    _player.setDataSource(SoundManageService.this,uri);
                    _player.setOnPreparedListener(new PlayerPreparedListener());
                    _player.setOnCompletionListener(new PlayerCompletionListener());
                    _player.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ServiceSample", "メディアプレーヤー準備失敗");
                }
        
                return START_NOT_STICKY;
            }
        
            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                super.onBind(intent);
                return null;
            }
        
            @Override
            public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
                return true;
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onDestroy(){
                if(_player.isPlaying()){
                    _player.stop();
                }
                _player.release();
                

            _player = null;
            super.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider to reduce your question(-s) and solve one problem at the time.

Comment: Thank you.I wanted to know how to show UI from notification  that once disappeared because of being tapped home button.I found the solution in japanese note!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the code (creating Intent for PendingIntent for Notification)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(SoundManageService.this,MainActivity.class);
```

to

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setClassName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), MainActivity.class.getName());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

made the problem solved.

https://qiita.com/imp954sti/items/e075fb8a99b68dda8180

↑this Japanese note helped me.